# Get distinct combinations along with count

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

So say in my database I have something like this:

```
col1      col2      col3

value1    value2    value1
value1    value1    value2
value1    value2    value1
value1    value3    value2
value2    value3    value1
```

I'm looking to query the database for the distinct combinations of column 1, 2 and 3 along with the count of the number of occurrences, i.e.:

```
col1      col2      col3      count

value1    value2    value1    2
value1    value1    value2    1
value1    value3    value2    1
value2    value3    value1    1
```

Order IS important!

Comment: It's discouraged to sign posts - they are signed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may be simpler than you expected:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've edited the question to be more specific to my requirements i.e. I will be needing to do this on more than two columns and the order is also important, please could you edit your answer accordingly as I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: @JamesElder: Don't change the nature of the question after a (correct) answer has been given. Start a new question for a different question. That said, my answer should still cover your problem. Just extend it with the third column. Order of columns is taken into account by default.

Comment: Sorry I tried to keep the question simple so that it is easier to answer then realised the query will be completely different if I add the third column... And I changed it to this `SELECT col1, col2, , col3 count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3;
ORDER  BY 1, 2, 3;` but it didn't work?

Comment: @JamesElder: Some obvious typos in your query (one of them in my answer as well). Updated.

Comment: Your right, sorry, I think I'm too sleepy right now to think properly! Your answer worked perfectly :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : can you please provide some reference to how this grouping will work. I am not able to understand in the group of "1","2" and "3" how respective groups will be formed. How this query will generate the correct result ?

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya: It's a  basic aggregation using positional parameters in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses. Start by reading the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY), [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES), [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : So 1,2 and 3 corresponds to the fields in the select statement. didn't know that.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya: Exactly.